# Modifying headers with IIS7 Application Request Routing

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, arr

I'm using IIS7 Application Request Routing in front of Tomcat as a replacement for ISAPI redirection. The basic reverse proxy function is working well, but I don't have enough information in the final request headers. My application exists on several subdomains: customerone.ourservice.com, customertwo.ourservice.com, etc. Each subdomain runs the same application, but with different branding graphics.

The application currently looks at the Host header to tell which branding to display. When I use the IIS7 reverse proxy, that information is lost. My headers are now:

```
accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-charset = ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
accept-encoding = gzip,deflate
accept-language = en-gb,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3
cookie = JSESSIONID=......
host = 127.0.0.1:8080
max-forwards = 10
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.15) Gecko/2009102815 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.15
x-original-url = /
x-forwarded-for = [iis7ip]:47567
x-arr-log-id = affbf81c-a5cf-4212-a43b-901cd9adcee6
connection = Keep-Alive
```

Is there any way I can insert the original Host header into the request headers passed on by the reverse proxy?

Comment: I don't now, but I've noticed that in our environment our headers are swapped out by IIS7 for application/xhtml+xml for no good reason.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Application Request Routing has an option to preserve the original host header: preserveHostHeader. This option is by default false. You can enable it with:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /preserveHostHeader:"True" /commit:apphost
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to test this any more (the application was decommissioned a few months ago), but your answer looks like the correct way to do this and I'm accepting it.

Comment: +1 - I had a similar issue with hosted YouTrack instance and this solved a problem with OpenID login not working

Comment: Anyone know why this only works in the `ApplicationHost.config` and not in each individual `web.config`??

Comment: note that appcmd.exe is in %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\ (use full path or add it to your Paths variable) more about this here http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

Comment: @StevendeSalas, it seems due to `<section name="proxy" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />` -- especially the `overrideModeDefault="Deny"` part.

Comment: Thanks! I have a wordpress site behind a reverse proxy and all links using rewrite failed until I applied this command. Instant solution. Seldom it goes this smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `preserveHostHeader` flag by hand.

```
    <proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="true" />

</system.webServer>
```

In the iis configuration gui you can find this value under `system.webServer/proxy`.

[image]

Comment: i updated the file at this location per this answer and it didn't work. Then I ran this command C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/prox
y /preserveHostHeader:"True" /commit:apphost

Which ended up fixing the issue. It gives a nice feedback when you run it: Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/proxy" for "MACHINE/W
EBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"