# IIS AAR - URL Rewrite for reverse proxy - how to send HTTP_HOST

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, arr

Trying to use AAR as a reverse proxy in front of several back end IIS servers.

- One public ip address assigned to the server running IIS/AAR
- Then outbound URL rewrite rules are setup to redirect to one of
  several back end servers depending on hostname.

Works somewhat, but always returns the back end servers default site (not the one mapped to a hostname) so it looks like the host name (HTTP_HOST) is not getting passed from the proxy server to the back end server.

*(I've verified bypassing the reverse proxy by editing hosts and the back end server returns the correct site bound to the host header)*

This is an example of the rule (192.168.0.99 is the internal server, site.myco.com is the hostname)

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.1.99/{R:1}" />                   
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Have tried putting sever variables so

```
    <!-- Guessing server.myco.com is hard coded -->
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="server.myco.com" />
    </serverVariables>

    <!-- Guessing picked up dynamically from incoming request host header -->
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
    </serverVariables>
```

But alas always returns the default binding - any ideas?

Comment: There is a new and better answer for this. Look at the bottom !!! simple through configuration editor on the webserver.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This post has the answer - [Modifying headers with IIS7 Application Request Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842885/modifying-headers-with-iis7-application-request-routing)

Need to enable preserveHostHeader - can't see how you do that in the UI but this works

Run this from command line to update Machine/webroot/apphost config

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/proxy -preserveHostHeader:true /commit:apphost
```

Comment: Definitely didn't know about this one before!

Comment: I found this in the UI for IIS 8.5: Server (or site)>Configuration Editor>system.webServer>Proxy. Copying the above into a run command or command line window is easier/faster, though.

Comment: This doesn't work if they are on the same server as it create a rewrite loop.

Comment: Better answer from Catch - with Configuration Editor.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with GUI. While on the root server click configuration editor, go to System.webServer -> proxy and set preserveProxyHeader to true.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that your server doesn't allow you to change the server variable `HTTP_HOST` when you rewrite the URL.

At the level of the website where the URL rewrite is applied:

[image: inetmgr]

Then click the `Add...` link on the right tab and add your `HTTP_HOST` variable:

[image: add HTTP_POST]

Comment: Not a bad guess but thats already done - you get a 500.500 error if its not in place telling you.