# IIS REST PUT requests 403 error on HTTPS (HTTP works fine), and only on Chrome/Safari, not Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, spring-security, web-deployment, iis-8, http-status-code-403

I'm running a Spring Boot application with an Angular 6 front end, on a Windows 8 server with IIS 8.5 set up as the reverse proxy (redirecting the site URL to localhost:8090) Originally I had a problem where all the PUT requests from the front end return 403, but only with Chrome and Safari, not Firefox. GET and POST requests are fine.

I am not an expert on setting up IIS, or proxy servers, by my guess is that this was because IIS was stripping out the headers that allowed CORS requests, and possibly other headers as well.

This original problem I fixed on the unsecure site, with the help of this SE: [Modifying headers with IIS7 Application Request Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842885/modifying-headers-with-iis7-application-request-routing)

However, now the same thing is happening on the HTTPS secure site, and I don't understand what setting I should change to make this work as well.

I would also like to better understand the reason why this is failing on the secure site but not the unsecure site, and also why it fails on Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: It is still not clear what kind of 403 you hit. Can you check IIS log files and find that out first? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: @LexLi  2019-01-06 16:59:52 10.6.94.21 PUT /api/assessment/single/715c6a73-13ac-4a8b-bbf2-6e5086aa2683 X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=6ce507e2-597a-4ae2-8c05-f12dfd845791&SERVER-STATUS=403 443 - [my ip address] Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/71.0.3578.98+Safari/537.36 [requesting URL] 403 0 0 109    There is no HTTP Status 443 so I can't see how this has much information.